# SelectionModel: only allow one selection in two grids

Tags: extjs

For better overview and to use the available screen space, I want two grids next to each other, but only one toolbar with buttons. The two grids are bound to different ChainedStores, but the underlying source store of the chained stores is the same. The ChainedStores have filters to create a partition of the records in the underlying store - one half on the left, the other on the right.

Clicking the buttons in the toolbar should perform actions on the selected record in either of these grids.

Is there a way to tell the selectionModels that I want only one record selected, in either the right or the left grid, but not one in each?

You can try around here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1vs4

Comment: No, there isn't. You would need to veto the selection using the `beforeselect` event as appropriate.

Comment: Thank you for confirming that I didn't overlook anything in the docs, @EvanTrimboli However, I don't want to veto any selection by the user. I now call setSelected([]) on the other grid's selectionModel. However, to get the grid to reflect the selection change, I always have to call getView().refresh() as well. Is this a bug? https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1vs5

Comment: Use `deselectAll();`. Not sure why you're calling `.setSelected({});`, especially since `selected` is private.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ExtJS does not support same selection model for two different grid.You have to handle it manually by code.

you can write `select` event listeners on each grid and on that event you can deselect record of another grid.

for `grid1`,

```
listeners :{
                 select : function(sel, record, index, eOpts){
                        sel.view.up('panel[name=main]').down('grid[name=grid2]').getSelectionModel().deselectAll();
                 }
           }
```

for `grid2`,

```
listeners :{
                 select : function(sel, record, index, eOpts){
                     sel.view.up('panel[name=main]').down('grid[name=grid1]').getSelectionModel().deselectAll();
                 }
           }
```

Please refer [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1vvs)